# Table Sorting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, filtering

I'm working on a table with filtering, I can get it to kind of function in fiddle but when I pop it back into DW and test the page it loses functionality. I have tried with the script on the page and inserted into the page, I'm at a loss of where to turn next so any help will be appreciated. I realize it's not complete and all the checkboxes arent set up properly but I really want to know (at this point) is why I lose functionality in dreamweaver - Correction when I test in a browser through Dreamweaver,I've also uploaded to a test server and still no functionality.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BryanGillet/jbvzayw4/)

```
$("input[name='filterStatus'], select.filter").change(function () {
    var classes = [];
    var stateClass = ""

    $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            classes.push('.'+$(this).val());
        }
    });

    $("select.filter").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != 'ZZ') {
            stateClass += "." + $(this).val();
        }
    });

    if (classes == "" && stateClass == "") {
        // if no filters selected, show all items
        $("#StatusTable tbody tr").show();
    } else {
        // otherwise, hide everything...
        $("#StatusTable tbody tr").hide();

        // then show only the matching items
        rows = $("#StatusTable tr" + stateClass).filter(classes.length ? classes.join(',') : '*');
        if (rows.size() > 0) {
            rows.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: To quote Homer Simposon: "Can't somebody else do it?" http://tablesorter.com/docs/.

Comment: Also don't test in Dreamweaver, it's not a browser, test in browsers instead. It's been ages since I've used Dreamweaver, can it even run javascript in its preview?

Comment: I would strongly advise against checking if your classes array is empty by comparing it to an empty string (`classes == ""`). I think  `classes.length === 0` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am testing in multiple browsers, I just can't figure out why my script is functioning sometimes in fiddle and then not at all in a browser.

Comment: I've also tried tablsorter.js but I need checkboxes

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure JTable will solve your problem.

You need to pass the data in the given example's format and it will allow to filter, search and paginate the data.

http://jtable.org/GettingStarted

Comment: I looked at JTable only problem is I need to use checkboxes to do the filtering and off of an html table. I can't use a database due to client constraints. I have a table that sorts by checkboxes but need to filter the results based on matching checkbox criteria.

Comment: For check box based filters, I am sure you need to write customized code